# Is this a switch?

Tags: identification

This is about a component from a toy ( [a very similar one here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Children-Colorful-Drum-Music-Toy-Percussion-Instrument-Baby-Kids-Early-Learning-Educational-Toy-Beat-Instrument-Hand/32866844390.html)) that I've repaired, just needed soldering on some cables. I've come across this component

[image]

This should be sensing/checking the drummer is touched so that music starts.

What is this component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a piezo buzzer/sensor [like this one](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/piezo-buzzers/8377840/?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_UK_EN_Passive_Components_Whoop-_-Piezo+Buzzers_Whoop-_-8377840&matchtype=&pla-346374886932&gclid=CjwKCAiAtdGNBhAmEiwAWxGcUjzyTvkGmrCbtg74hpHHocREoN_eH-BkcNmEOsGkYEjeIUcvTCKoVxoCUJYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds): -

[image]

And it can be both used to generate sound and used to generate an electrical signal when subjected to certain movements (like a drum stick).

- [Wiki piezo electric sensors](https://reprap.org/wiki/Underbed_Piezo-electric_sensors).
- [Piezo drum kit](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/330)
- [Piezos for Electronic Drums](http://www.v-drumtips.com/piezos/)

[image]

GIF image from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity#/media/File:SchemaPiezo.gif).

Comment: Yes, it must be this one and it is used for detecting the drum. There is already a speaker for sound.

Comment: It's highly likely that it's similar to the exact one in your toy but, it's highly unlikely that it is identical. There are hundreds to choose from and you'd match them dimensionally first then make electrical comparisons.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly true if I need a replacement. I was able to solder the middle cable hoping that it will work.

Comment: Good luck @kelalaka

Comment: I did after two tries and the toy is working and sent back. I feared that the soldering will melt the layer :)

Answer (score 3):

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Limei-Xu-2/publication/264439939/figure/fig4/AS:670030199021578@1536759056188/PZT-ceramic-transducer-array-see-online-version-for-colours.ppm
[image]

It's likely a PZT ceramic can that generates a piezoelectric xxx mV noise to trigger a transistor-controlled LED circuit. An electret mic would be more sensitive and robust but costs a dozen cents more. So it's a cheap sensor but with very fragile filament wire from the electrode. Not like @Andy's huge disk but similar in function.